# How to make several rows with foreach?

Tags: php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am using Laravel 5.8 and in my controller I am showing 4 elements with `paginate()`:

```
public function index()
{
    $proyects = Proyect::latest()->paginate(4);
    return view('proyect.index', compact('proyects'));
}
```

In the view the 4 elements are in a single row but I would like to show 2 elements for each row.

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-10 col-lg-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="card-deck">
        @forelse($proyects as $proyect)

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ $proyect->title }}</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
                 {{ $proyect->descripcion }}</h6>
                <p class="card-text">You can use the cap image as an 
                    overlay for the body</p>
                <a href="{{ route('proyect.show', $proyect) }}" 
                    class="card-link">Ver mas</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">
                 {{ $proyect->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</small>
            </div>
        </div>

        @empty

        <li> Empty </li>

        @endforelse
    </div>
</div>
```

How to show 2 items per row instead of all items in a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
public function index()
{
    $proyects = Proyect::latest()->paginate(10);
    return view('proyect.index', compact('proyects'));
}
```

array_chunk is a php function ca splice your array.

```html
@forelse(array_chunk($proyects->all(),2) as $rows)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($rows as $proyect)
            <div class="col-10 col-lg-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="card-deck">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ $proyect->title }}</h5>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{ $proyect->descripcion }}</h6>
                            <p class="card-text">You can use the cap image as overlay for the body</p>
                            <a href="{{ route('proyect.show', $proyect) }}" class="card-link">Ver mas</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <small class="text-muted">{{ $proyect->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    @empty
    <div>Empty ...</div>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is your solution:

```
<div class="row">
@forelse($proyects as $proyect)
<div class="col-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="card-deck">


        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ $proyect->title }}</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
                 {{ $proyect->descripcion }}</h6>
                <p class="card-text">You can use the cap image as an 
                    overlay for the body</p>
                <a href="{{ route('proyect.show', $proyect) }}" 
                    class="card-link">Ver mas</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">
                 {{ $proyect->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</small>
            </div>
        </div>

        @empty

        <li> Empty </li>


    </div>
@endforelse
</div>
```